# Uploading Image on deployed bluemix app

Tags: python, event-handling, ibm-cloud, image-uploading, openwhisk

I need to make an app, that waits for an image to be uploaded then executes some code to process it and then waits for a new image. The app has to be deployed on bluemix and run continuously there.

I have no idea of web programming, so every documentation you can recommend is welcomed.

My main problems is how to make a post method that will replace this in my current app:

```
open(join(dirname(__file__), './test.jpg'), 'rb') as image_file
```

and a way to make the app do that repeatedly.

Comment: I added the OpenWhisk tag because what you are trying to do could be done by an event-driven serverless framework like OpenWhisk - on Bluemix

Comment: @data_henrik    Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: @data_henrik - i thought OpenWhisk didn't support a file system - so where would the file be uploaded too?